# How to retrieve(in controller) and display video in a Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have successfully retrieved the video name with its extension from the database but it's not displaying on a blade.
This the result when I retrive and dump

`$video_data = DB::select('select * from videos')[4]->file ?? null;`
`dd($video_data);`

**"big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4"**

```
Display in Laravel
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{URL('/storage/Atayads/Video/'.$video_data)}}" allowfullscreen>
</video>
```

Note I am displaying only one video that is according to an array above.

Now the problem I am getting that it's not displaying video, nor an error

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating symbolic link according to laravel docs

```
php artisan storage:link
```

this will create a symlink from public/storage to storage/app/public & you can access the file from /storage/app/public

```
http://example.com/storage/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4
```

for the full path you can use something like below

```
$path = storage_path('public/' . $video_data);
```